# Multiplying string

Tags: c, string

I want to make a lines of stars, each line containing more then the previous one. The point of my problem is that I don´t know how to multiply strings in C.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{    
     int max = 10
     for (int i = 1; i <= max; ++i){
         printf("*"*(2 * i - 1);
     }

}
```

Comment: You could use two nested loops. The outer loop for each line, the inner loop for the stars on each line.

Comment: Okay, so let's try another approach. What language do you know that _does_ support multiplying strings? What does it even mean to multiply a string?

Answer (score 2):

You can just repeat printing the desired number of strings.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{    
     int max = 10; // a semicolon is added to make it compile
     for (int i = 1; i <= max; ++i){
         for (int j = 0; j < (2 * i - 1); j++){ // repeat (2 * i - 1) times
             printf("*");
         }
         printf("\n"); // separate lines
     }

}
```

I respect the original code, so some points that are not good (meaningless including of non-standard `conio.h` and non-standard definition of `main()` (instead of `int main(void)`)) remains.

Answer (score 2):

The language semantics do not support what you are trying to do.  In C a string is not a first class type in any case - it is simply an array of `char`,  so all string handling is performed through functions; you cannot perform direct operations on them; and even if you could I doubt *multiply* would be one of them - it has a very limited use case easily implemented using simpler operations.

In this case you do not in fact need repeated string replication (or multiply as you refer to it) since you are outputting the string directly so have no need to store the string and the associated memory allocation issues that entails.  Rather you simply need repeated string output.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void printRepeatString( const char* str, int n )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < n; n++ )
    {
        printf( "%s", str ) ;
    }
}

int main( void )
{    
     const int max = 10
     for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++ )
     {
         printRepeatString( "*", (2 * i) - 1 ) ;
         putchar( '\n' ) ;
     }

    return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to "multiplying" a string of `'*'` is to create the longest one and then print a truncated portion of it.

Use `"%.*s", n, s` to print a character array `s` up to `n` characters.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 10

int main(void) {
  char s[2 * MAX] = {0};
  memset(s, '*', 2 * MAX - 1);

  for (int i = 1; i <= MAX; ++i) {
    printf("%.*s\n", 2 * i - 1, s);
  }

}
```

Output

```
*
***
*****
*******
*********
***********
*************
***************
*****************
*******************
```